# update statement set multiple columns using case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been testing an update that sets multiple columns based on the results of a case.  In all the similar posts and examples i have found the code below should work. After the code runs I would expect id 1 to have both f1 and f2 = 'Y' but only f1 = 'Y'.

Is my syntax wrong somewhere here or is the case stopping after any condition is satisfied?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
create table test.dbo.testa<br>
(
    id int,
    f1 char,
    f2 char,
    f3 char
)

insert into test.dbo.testa (id)
select 1 union all 
select 2 union all 
select 3

create table test.dbo.testb
(
    id int,
    f1 varchar(2) 
) 

insert into test.dbo.testb (id, f1)
select 1, 'f1' union all 
select 1, 'f2' union all 
select 2, 'f1' union all 
select 2, 'f2'

update x
set x.f1 = case when y.f1 = 'f1' then 'Y' else x.f1 end,
    x.f2 = case when y.f1 = 'f2' then 'Y' else x.f2 end
from test.dbo.testa x
inner join test.dbo.testb y 
on x.id = y.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my syntax wrong somewhere here or is the case stopping after any
>   condition is satisfied?

Is nothing wrong with your syntax. The problem is how is `UPDATE ... FROM ...` statement is written. For such `UPDATE` statements it's important to know that for every row from the target table `dbo.TestA x` should be no more than one row in the source table `dbo.TestB y`. For this we must look at the join predicate: `ON x.id = y.id`. But it seems to be not your case because for every row from `dbo.TestA` there are two rows in `dbo.TesteB` (example: x.id `1` ->> y.id : `1 - f1` , `1 - f2` and x.id `2` ->> y.id : `2 - f1` , `2 - f2`). In such cases, SQL Server will *pick up* for every row from target table `dbo.TestA` *only one row* from the source table `dbo.TestB`. This is the reason why original `UPDATE` statement has following results:

```
id  f1   f2   f3
--- ---- ---- ----
1   Y    NULL NULL -- column f2 is not updated
2   Y    NULL NULL -- column f2 is not updated
3   NULL NULL NULL
```

Also, if you change the order of rows in the source table `dbo.TableB` (for example)

```
truncate table test.dbo.testb;
insert into test.dbo.testb (id, f1)
select 1, 'f1' union all 
select 1, 'f2' union all 
select 2, 'f2' union all 
select 2, 'f1'
```

the you will get different results (using the same `UPDATE` statement):

```
id f1   f2   f3
-- ---- ---- ----
1  Y    NULL NULL
2  Y    Y    NULL <- different results
3  NULL NULL NULL
```

These cases should be avoided because, as you can see, the results of `UPDATE` statement are not predictable.

> Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE  x
SET     x.f1 = y.colf1,
        x.f2 = y.colf2 
FROM    dbo.TestA x
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  b.id, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.f1 = 'f1' THEN b.f1 END) AS colf1,
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.f1 = 'f2' THEN b.f1 END) AS colf2
    FROM    dbo.TestB b
    GROUP BY b.id
) AS y ON x.id = y.id;
```

or

```
UPDATE  x
SET     x.f1 = y.f1,
        x.f2 = y.f2 
FROM    dbo.TestA x
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  pvt.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  b.id, b.f1 as value
        FROM    dbo.TestB b
    ) src
    PIVOT( MAX(src.value) FOR src.value IN([f1], [f2]) ) pvt
) AS y ON x.id = y.id;
```

For the last example, `(...) y` derived table

```
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT  b.id, b.f1 as value
    FROM    dbo.TestB b
) src
PIVOT( MAX(src.value) FOR src.value IN([f1], [f2]) ) pvt
```

generates the following results:

```
id f1   f2
-- ---- ----
1  f1   f2
2  f1   f2
```

Note: Also you should define the maximum length for dbo.TestA f1, f2 and f3 columns:

```
create table test.dbo.testa
(
    id int,
    f1 varchar(2) ,
    f2 varchar(2) ,
    f3 varchar(2) 
)
```

Comment: I skipped the aggregation part, as it wasn't at all clear what (max, min, other) might produce the proper value to update with.

Answer (score 0):

The internal processing logic on your code would go something as follows:

- Join the two tables
- Update the "target" table based on the results

This works fine IF the result of the join produces no more than one row per row in the "target" table. Here, however, there are two rows generated for both of the target table's rows:

```
select *
from testa x
inner join testb y 
on x.id = y.id
```

produces

```
id  f1  f2  f3  id  f1
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    1   f1
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    1   f2
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    2   f1
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    2   f2
```

It would seem that SQL considers only the "first" resulting row for each "target" row, and performs its updates based on that (and note that the "first" such row is fairly arbitrarily selected).